# Designing you SQLite DB in anticipation of your future code?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

Here is my situation: 
A senior member/boss in a company using my app will be able to assign "tasks" to his/her employees. A "task" may contain many "sub-tasks". Right now my only requirement is to make a "task" and a "sub_task" table in my database like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `tasks` (
`id`    INTEGER NOT NULL,
`title` TEXT NOT NULL,
`description`   TEXT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id)
)
```

and sub_tasks:

```
CREATE TABLE `sub_tasks` (
`id`    INTEGER NOT NULL,
`title` TEXT NOT NULL,
`description`   TEXT NOT NULL,
`tasks_id`  INTEGER NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id)
FOREIGN KEY(tasks_id) REFERENCES tasks(id)
)
```

As you can see I use `tasks_id` in sub_tasks table as a foreign key referenced to `id` in `tasks` table. Right now it serves my requirement well. But in future when I will create an `Employee` class, the situation will be like this: A Senior member will/can assign many tasks to a single employee and every task may/may not contain many sub_tasks. How can you design you database in anticipation of this requirement so that it will not break down my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can tasks be assigned to multiple employees, or will they be assigned to only one employee at a time?

If it's the former, you'll need another table, "employee_tasks" or something of the sort. I won't go into this much because I feel it's the least likely option, but basically you create unique employee/task pairs and you can ensure that multiple employees have completed the same task.

If it's the latter, all you'll need is a new column in the task table for "employee_id." That employee is now in charge of that task. How you choose to get all the information is up to your personal preference and how many db hits you're comfortable with, but I'd personally select all tasks for a given employee, and then for each task I'd find its subtasks. If you want to make fewer db hits you can find all tasks, then find all subtasks through a join, and then match the tasks in memory. Those are the two "easy" ways I know of doing it, though I wouldn't be surprised if there's something a bit more clever out there.